# Wordpress Administrator access to plugins page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, administrator

I recently downloaded the Advanced Access Manager Plugin for wordpress and accidentally removed the capability of the administrator to view the plugins page. Is there a place I can access the users/administrators capabilities with the wordpress php files to fix my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to the Access Control page i.e. http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=aam
- Go to the Capability option and click the plus icon to "Add New Capability"
- For the Capability Name add each of the following:

  - Activate Plugins
  - Update Plugins
  - Delete Plugins
  - Install Plugins
  - Edit Plugins
- After adding the above refresh the page (might need to do a hard refresh).
- The Plugin options should be added back.